# WCF Could not find endpoint time to time

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, endpoint

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'XXXServiceReference.XXXService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

exception however I get this error time to time (1/3 fail) What might be the issue here is my config file

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://address:8091/XXXService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService"
        contract="XXXServiceReference.IXXXService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I define my service like

```
private XXXServiceClient sClient;

 bool success = false;
 int numOfEntrance = 0;
 while (!success && (numOfEntrance < 20))
 {
      numOfEntrance++;
      try
      {
           sClient = new XXXServiceClient();
           success = true;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          success = false;
          Thread.Sleep(500);
          if (numOfEntrance == 19)
          MessageBox.Show("Connection Problem");
      }
  }
```

I tried this because it enters time to time. I thought while might be a chance to get rid of this problem but it didnt. What might be the issue ? Could it be because of service provider. Btw I tried to remove "XXXServiceClient" part from contract however it didnt work.

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  IIS?

Comment: Service is written by another company. And they told us that they re using IIS. Could it be a good idea to use this service as webservice?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by either instability in the IIS hoster OR the hosting site is idling out and then has to warm back up on the next call.  The following post describes how you can configure the IIS `applicationHost.config` to auto start:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series